# JQuery AJAX Read files from folder backwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file

i am using this code for website to load all images from folder into page. But as u can see i am using prepend command because images are named like "0001","0002","0003" so script first reads 0001 file and i need to show latest number first.

Is there way to read name of files backward?
(first 0003 then 0002, 0001..)

Code i am using now (i found this code there on stackoverflow):

```
var dir = "img/Torty/";
var fileextension = ".jpg";
$.ajax({
    url: dir
    , success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
            if (filename.indexOf("+s+") >= 0) {
                var splitted = filename.split("+");
                $("#tortySem").prepend("<p><img src='" + dir + filename + "'></p>");
                $("#tortySem").prepend("<p>Torta " + parseInt(splitted[0]) + "   Váha " + splitted[1] + "Kg</p>");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is `filename` variable which references `"0001"` - `"0003"`? Where are `"0001"` - `"0003"` references stored or incremented?

Comment: in filename there is "0001+12+s+v+" for example so when i split it with "+" on index 0 there is this number

Comment: Could you use `.append()` instead of `.prepend()`? You could also create an array containing `["0003", "0002", "0001"]` then iterate array, appending or prepending image in order of contents of array

Comment: there is this folder where are files stored:
http://asd01.esy.es/img/Torty/
When i use append, latest files would be at the bottom of webpage and i need them first that is why prepend

Comment: Is expected result for file including `"0003"` to be at top of element container?

Comment: yes 0003 should be at the top
it works with prepend but first it loads image 0001 etc...
when there are 100 images it takes while to load latest that is shown as first

Comment: Have you tried using `.append()` and reversing order of requesting images?

Comment: that Would be great but i am not sure how to reverse that :D

Comment: Do `a` elements at `$(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")")` contain file names including `"0001"` - `"000n"`? And are the file names in numeric order within the document?

Comment: I am not sure what this a means. I didnt declare it anywhere. This whole code is copied and i do not very understand how it reads from folder.
This is the online folder which script reads from:  asd01.esy.es/img/Torty
This script just find all files with extension .jpg there is no variable with stored filenames

Comment: The `<a>` elements which are retrieved from `data` using `$(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")")`. Are the `<a>` elements in numeric order relevant to `"0001"`?

Comment: yes i think.
in the folder there is first 0001 then 0002 etc...
Edit: But i dont have exactly reference to images, i just find all files that contains .jpg extension and for each there is this prepend command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.toArray()`, `Array.prototype.reverse()`, `.append()`

```
$($(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").toArray().reverse())
.each(function () {
  var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "")
                 .replace("http:///", "");
  if (filename.indexOf("+s+") >= 0) {
    var splitted = filename.split("+");
    $("#tortySem")
    .append("<p><img src='" + dir + filename + "'></p>");
    $("#tortySem")
    .append("<p>Torta " 
      + parseInt(splitted[0]) 
      + "   Váha " 
      + splitted[1] 
      + "Kg</p>");
  }
});
```

```js
var data = "<div><a href=0001>0001</a><a href=0002>0002</a><a href=0003>0003</a></div>";

var n = "000";

$($(data).find("a:contains(" + n + ")").toArray().reverse())
.each(function() {
  $("div").append(this, "<br>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thank you very much!